# Can NLog properties be conditional?

Tags: nlog

I have the following

```xml
<target name="foo" ...>
   <property name="bar" value="${identity}"/>
</target>
```

Is it possible to make the identity conditional ?  I've tried using `${identity}:when=logger!='MyNamespace.MyLogger'` but that doesn't work

Comment: Should the value be conditional or the whole element/property?

Comment: The Value.  I'd like to send '' for the condition.

Comment: The the answer below should work :)

Answer (score 0):

The value could be conditional, when the the type of the property is `Layout`.

Fully skip the property would be possible, but that depends of the target.